# the transformation of Laplace equation

Tags: vectors

If the 2D Laplace equation is invariant under the following transformations:
$x'^{i}=\frac{x^{i}-b^i x^2}{1-2\vec{b} \cdot \vec{x}+b^{2}x^2 } $ and u'(x')=u(x) . $b^{i}$ is a two-dimensional constant vector.I don't know how to prove this conclusion.

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Comment: I want to know if under this transformation, the equation is invariant. And i don't  know how to prove it

Comment: Please do not write $x^2$ and $b^2$. Surely you’ve tried to write out the chain rule computation. Where do you get a problem?

Comment: I find it too difficult to solve it due to the complex expression.